# Approximation under a continuous linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces. Let $T:X\to Y$ be linear and continuous with $\text{ran}(T)\neq Y$ but $\overline{\text{ran}(T)}=Y$. I want to show that there is a $y\in Y$ such that for any $(x_n)\subset X$ with $Tx_n\to y$, we have
$\|x_n\|\to\infty$.

First of all it is clear that $y\in Y\setminus\text{ran}(T)$. I think the statement can be proven similar to the open mapping theorem but I am lacking an argument to show that there is an $R>0$ such that $\overline{T(B_R(0))}$ has non-empty interior. Please do not give my a full proof; a little hint suffices completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't want to see the full proof, I will hide some consecutive hints (pass with the mouse on the hiding bars).

First hint:

> Argue by contradiction: suppose $\forall y\in Y\,\,\exists x_n\in X: T(x_n)\to y \,\,\mbox{and}\,\, \|x_n\|_X\le C=C(y).$

Then we can consider:

> $$\bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty}\overline{ T(B_N(0))}$$

Then we have:

> $$\bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty}\overline{ T(B_N(0))}=Y$$ by the absurd hypothesis.

And we can conclude:

> Using Baire's theorem we have that there is $N$ such that $\overline{T(B_N(0))}$ has nonempty interior. But then $ran (T)=Y$, that is a contradiction with the hypotheses of the problem.

Comment: fair enough. I am wondering why I didn’t get before. However, thanks a lot.